# OpenGL glColorPointer renders black

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, vbo, vertex-shader

Here is the breakdown: I load a model from an obj file and store into buffers as follows :vbo for vertexes, ibo for indexes , vao for state and num_indices an int with total indices number. To get the model color I exported a separate off file and extracted color information per vertex and I have an array with 4 values for each vertex so the size of the array is vertexno*4. My draw function looks like this.

```
    glUniformMatrix4fv(location_model_matrix,1,false,glm::value_ptr(model_matrix));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(location_view_matrix,1,false,glm::value_ptr(view_matrix));
    glUniformMatrix4fv(location_projection_matrix,1,false,glm::value_ptr(projection_matrix));
    //glUniform4f(location_object_color,1,1,1,1);
    glBindVertexArray(mesh_vao);
    glEnableClientState( GL_COLOR_ARRAY );
    glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
    glColorPointer( 4, GL_FLOAT, 0, colors );
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,mesh_num_indices,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
```

And the model renders black. I also have some cubes drawn in the draw function which I color using glUniform4f(location_object_color,rgba) and if I uncomment then the loaded mesh will take the same color as the last drawn cube.

In my constructor I have something like this:

```
    glClearColor(0.5,0.5,0.5,1);
    glClearDepth(1);            
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    gl_program_shader = lab::loadShader("shadere\\shader_vertex.glsl", "shadere\\shader_fragment.glsl");
    location_model_matrix = glGetUniformLocation(gl_program_shader, "model_matrix");
    location_view_matrix = glGetUniformLocation(gl_program_shader, "view_matrix");
    location_projection_matrix = glGetUniformLocation(gl_program_shader, "projection_matrix");
    location_object_color = glGetUniformLocation(gl_program_shader, "object_color");
```

If need be I can provide my shader_vertex and shader_fragment , I considered it to be a problem but im not so sure so if anyone knows why my model isn't being colored please throw a hand.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but could it have anything to do with lighting?

Comment: There is something wrong in your logic. You say you set color via `glUniform4f(location_object_color,rgba)`. But you also try to set color via an vertex attribute? Please show your shaders (both of them), since they are responsible for determining the color of the produced fragments. As a side note: you are mixing deprecated acd core functionality. You really should use generic vertex attributes and drop all of thos deprecated builtin attributes.

Comment: Please post your shaders, since we need to make sure they use the color attribute as well / correctly

Comment: #version 330
layout(location = 0) out vec4 out_color;

uniform vec4 object_color;


void main(){

 out_color = object_color;
}                                                                        and the shader vertex :                                                         #version 330

layout(location = 0) in vec3 in_position;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 in_normal;

uniform mat4 model_matrix, view_matrix, projection_matrix;

void main(){

 gl_Position = projection_matrix*view_matrix*model_matrix*vec4(in_position,1); 
}

Comment: Yes well , i commented the glUniform4f so i only use the vertex coloring.Also shouldn't it override it anways ? I can also color the cubes with vertex attribute but for the meantime i just draw the model with only vertex attribute so thats no problem. I have no lighting set at the meantime.

Comment: You are using GLSL 330 (OpenGL 3.3). Why on earth are you using the deprecated fixed-function pointers to store your vertex position and color? There are some OpenGL 3.3 implementations that only support core (e.g. Mac OS X). You should switch to vertex attirbs ASAP for better portability.